# Move column from one csv file to another and move its values where ID matches

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm wondering if the following would be possible with pandas in Python:
I have two CSV files.

products.csv :

```
Id  ProductName EngagedUsers
1   Tennis Ball     17
2   Football Shoes  33
3   Electric Guitar 45
4   Drum Pad        6
```

orders.csv :

```
Id  OrderNo OrderDestination
1    200         London
3    22          Madrid
2    1           Lisbon
```

Based on those two files I would like to generate a new CSV file that shows the following:

newOrders.csv:

```
Id  ProductName EngagedUsers    OrderNo
1   Tennis Ball     17            200
2   Football Shoes  33            1
3   Electric Guitar 45            22
```

From my understanding I have to open those two files as data frames and merge them on 'Id' column and specifying the columns I need and then only the values for matching IDs will be present in the newOrders.csv file + records with no matching 'Id' will not be present in the file. Could you please help? I started like this so far but results are not as I expect:

```
 import pandas as pd

 df_products = pd.read_csv("products.csv")
 df_orders = pd.read_csv("orders.csv")

 df_new = pd.merge(df_products, df_orders, on='Id')

 Id = df_new["Id"]
 ProductName = df_new["ProductName"]
 EngagedUsers = df_new["EngagedUsers"]
 OrderNo = df_new["OrderNo"]


 header = ["Id", "ProductName", "EngagedUsers", "OrderNo"]
 df.to_csv('newOrders.csv', columns = header)
```

Could you please help with this? Or maybe there is an easier approach?

Answer (score 0):

you can sort by id in both dataframes. this is possible with `df.sort_values(by=['id'])` Then just set a new dataframe and get the columns from the other dataframes which you like e.g. `df_new['ProductName'] = df['ProductName']`